# C++ Iterate through a list of structs of structs

Tags: c++, list, struct

I'm having an issue with accessing the list of a struct in a struct:

```
struct  B{
  string word;
};

struct A{
  list<B> message;
};
```

Putting data into the data structure is no problem:

```
list<A> messageList;
while(--there are messages to be found--){
  list<B> wordList;
  do{
    string buff;
    wordList.push_front({buff});
  }while(--there are words to be found--);
  messageList.push_front({wordList});
}
```

But know I would like to read each word of a message:

```
list<A>::iterator itMessage;
for(itMessage = messageList.begin(); itMessage != messageList.end(); itMessage++){
```

Here I'm stuck do I make an iterator out of an iterator?

```
  list<itMessage->message>::iterator itWord;
```

Or a list of a list?

```
  list<list<??>>::iterator itWord;
```

Comment: Why not simply use two range based for loops and the `auto` keyword?

Answer (score 3):

First, iterate over messages, then iterate over words:

```
struct A {
    auto begin() {
        return message.begin();
    }
    auto end() {
        return message.end();
    }

    list<B> message;
};

for (auto& message : messageList)
    for (auto& word : message)
    {
        ...
    }
```

If you want a single iterator over words in a `messageList`, you have to write it yourself.